# How to prevent/fix panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm new to golang. From the code below, sometimes `color` could be nil, but I still need to call `GetCategory`. This would result in the err below:
`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

How to call `GetCategory` gracefully and avoid the err?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type event struct {
    color      *string
    Category      *string
}

func GetCategory(color string) (*string, error) {
    var category string
    if strings.HasPrefix(color, "red") {
        category = "likes"
    } else if strings.HasPrefix(color, "blue") {
        category = "dislikes"
    }
    return &category, nil
}


func main() {
             category := "red"
            eventObj := event{
        Category:   &category,
            }
    fmt.Println(GetCategory(*eventObj.color))
    
}
```

Comment: `eventObj.color` is `nil`, so dereferencing it panics. You initialize the `eventObj.category` field, likely you want to do that with `color`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `*string` instead of `string` for the fields?  The `string` type avoids the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check if something is nil, you just *do that*, and act accordingly. For example:

```
func GetCategory(color *string) (*string, error) {
  if color == nil {
    return nil, errors.New("Color is nil")
  }
  // ...
```

There is no [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator), [safe navigation operator](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) etc.

If something might be `nil`, you simply check for `nil` with a straightforward equality or inequality check (`== nil` or `!= nil`) before you use it.